# How do I render to texture if my GL Shader Language version is 1.30 (i.e. without layout qualifier)?

Tags: opengl

I've followed [Tutorial 14](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/) all the way through and got it working on one of my computers. However when I build and run the project on a laptop I have, I get an error about not supporting GLSL 3.30.

This second laptop is running linux and doesn't have a dedicated GPU. When I run `glxinfo` I see this line among the others:

> OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30

I've written some "hello world" style shaders for `#version 130` and got them to work but to do so I had to give up on my approach of rendering to a texture and then rendering that to a quad on screen. I read somewhere (can't remember where, if I find it I'll link it) that the layout qualifier wasn't introduced until 1.40 so I'm a bit stuck.

My goal is to render to a texture at a large size (4k?), save that texture to a file on disk (using `glTexImage` probably, haven't gotten that far yet), and then render that texture to screen at a different size (1080 or 720 probably) so I can watch the rendering process. If I use `glReadPixels` then the size and shape of the window affects the image. Since I can't render to texture right now, I can't get 4k frame images. I can only get frame images the size of the window.

In GLSL 1.30, how can I render to texture without the layout qualifier?

Comment: Which graphics card do you have? Parts of your question are completely unclear: `glTexImage` has nothing to do with saving textures to disk. Do you mean `glGetTexImage`? If your graphic card is that old, you should also check whether it supports the texture size you need.

Comment: @BDL Their is no graphics card. It's integrated graphics. Intel i5. It's fairly new. Only a year or two old.

Comment: An i5 has an integrated graphics chip. Which one do you have?

Answer (score 2):

The old stlye alternative for specifying the location of an output variable is  [`glBindFragDataLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindFragDataLocation.xhtml). This function has exactly the same effect as a layout qualifier in the shader. Note, that this function has to be called before linking the program.